# Understanding Regular Expression for the Below Template

Tags: regex, perl, svn, bugzilla, scmbug

I am installing scmbug to integrate bugzilla with svn on windows.
After a whole day fight with scmbug. Seems like i made it to get off the ground.

I entered the commit comment as

---

bug 3

bug3

test test test

bla bla bla

---

But it give me error like 
the below

Scmbug error 3: No list of bug ids was found that matches the log_bugid_regex '^\s*bug\s*([\d|\s|,|#]*?):' and log_bugid_split_regex ',\s?#|\s?#|,|\s+' in the log message 'bug 3

grepping the syntax leads me to the conf file.

So expecting help to the understand the below regex and its valid input.

```
log_template => {
    # The log_bugid_regex is a regular expression that must
    # set the unnamed variable $1 to the bug number, or list
    # of bug numbers. It is checked for a match as: m/$regex/s

    log_bugid_regex => '^\s*bug\s*([\d|\s|,|#]*?):',

        # The log_bugid_split_regex is a regular expression
        # describing how a list of bug ids will be split in
        # individual bug numbers. It is split as: /$regex/

        log_bugid_split_regex => ',\s?#|\s?#|,|\s+',

    # The log_body_regex is a regular expression that must set
    # the unnamed variable $1 to the log comment. It is
    # checked for a match as: m/$regex/s

    log_body_regex => '^\s*bug.*?:\s*(.*)'

    },
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\s*bug\s*([\d|\s|,|#]*?):
```

You have a colon at the end of the regex; your commit message does not have it. Therefore, it doesn't match.

The regexes are meant to match entries like:

```
bug #2,#666: Corrected the number of the beast
```

The `#` are optional.

Comment: Yea.. Got that. thanks for that. can we also get some explanation for the valid input to all the three regex.